# how to disable(Hide) application icon from SwitchApplication popup screen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

i am developing an application which contain alternative entry point.
and i put tick mark in "Do not display in Blackberry Home screen". here it is working fine it does not show icon on the home screen. but my problem is that

> when i am click on SwitchApplication from menu(Home screen), the alternative entry point icon is showing on the popup screen like following image. i dont want to show that icon.i want hide that icon programatically.

please help me [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just override this method into our application
like following

```
private static boolean flag=false;
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StartUp startUp;
        if(args!=null && args.length>0 && args[0].equals("gui")){
            flag=false;
            startUp = new StartUp("gui");
            startUp.enterEventDispatcher();

        }else{
            flag=true;
            startUp = new StartUp();
            startUp.enterEventDispatcher();
        }
    }
```

i override this method

```
protected boolean acceptsForeground() {

        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide app if it's service. Set system module (systemmodule) to true for bb ant tools. There is similar options for JDE and Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I ended up using that worked for me. I had tried putting the acceptsForeground in my main launcher class at first, but then put it in PushListener itself instead to prevent it from appearing in the running tasks menu. Worked fine.

*Launcher Class*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("gui")) {
        MyApp app = new MyApp();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    } else {
        PushListener.waitForInstance().start();
    }
}
```

*PushListener Class*

```
protected boolean acceptsForeground() {
    return false; // You could use a variable instead if you wanted.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple if you use blackberry eclipse plugin.

open "blackberry_description_app.xml", just check this: Don't display the app icon on blackberry home screen.